# How to do unit test with Kitten UI

Tags: reactjs, react-native, unit-testing, jestjs, react-native-ui-kitten

Currently i'm using jest to do unit test with react native app (expo CLI), bu when testing render it's totally fine when i import any components from react-native, but if i do from other (such as react-native-ui-kitten). There will be error like image below. Can someone pls help me
Thanks in advance !

[Here's when i do snapshot with react-native component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7XOn.png)

[When i do snapshot that exists kitten UI component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlLlq.png)

[I'm configure "transformIgnorePatterns" in package.json but not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDzWA.png)

My package.json

```
  "jest": {
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(tsx|ts)?$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json"
    ]
  },
  "transformIgnorePatterns": [
    "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|react-clone-referenced-element|@react-native-community|@ui-kitten/components|react-native-ui-kitten|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base)"
  ],
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "npm run lint",
      "pre-push": "npm run lint"
    }
  }
```

My jest.config.js

```
const {defaults} = require('jest-config');
module.exports = {
  // ...
  moduleFileExtensions: [...defaults.moduleFileExtensions, 'ts', 'tsx'],
  preset: "jest-expo",
  // ...
};
```

My babel.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const Config = require('./config');

// FIXME: Resolve `transform[stderr]: Could not resolve` command-line warnings.
// FIXME: Reproducible when starting with clearing cache (npm start -- -c)
//
// TODO: Framework path aliasing even not needed here. Replace?
// TODO: Replace nested package.json-s with aliases

const moduleResolverConfig = {
  root: path.resolve('./'),
  alias: {
    '@kitten/theme': path.resolve(Config.KITTEN_PATH, 'theme'),
    '@kitten/ui': path.resolve(Config.KITTEN_PATH, 'ui'),
    '@eva-design/eva': path.resolve(Config.MAPPING_PATH),
    '@eva-design/processor': path.resolve(Config.PROCESSOR_PATH),
  },
};

module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);

  const presets = [
    'babel-preset-expo',
  ];

  const plugins = [
    ['module-resolver', moduleResolverConfig],
  ];

  return { presets, plugins };
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure to ignore 3rd-party modules in test environment. In jest.config.js:

```js
testPathIgnorePatterns: [
  '<rootDir>/node_modules',
],
```

Also, there is a well-known workaround for it if that fails:

```js
transformIgnorePatterns: [
  "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|react-clone-referenced-element|@react-native-community|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|sentry-expo|native-base|@ui-kitten)"
]
```

Comment: i've tried to add both in jest.config.js, but it does not work :(
Have i done anything wrong 
`const {defaults} = require('jest-config');
module.exports = {
  // ...
  testPathIgnorePatterns: [
    '<rootDir>/node_modules',
  ],
  moduleFileExtensions: [...defaults.moduleFileExtensions, 'ts', 'tsx'],
  preset: "jest-expo",
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|react-clone-referenced-element|@react-native-community|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|sentry-expo|native-base|@ui-kitten)"
  ]
  // ...
};`